# access elements in redux state tree

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to render information contained in the final nodes of the tree, like img, popularity, name, id, url...etc inside a little box an then pass that to its parent.

[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsz7O.jpg)

I'm trying to access the *most children* items in the state tree which Redux puts together here:  however react is complaining that I cant render objects, but when I code a markup element using a key and `.map` I get a `<ul>` of strings `[obj][Obj]` to the screen instead of the child elements I want and all its props.

How can render child elements (and props) from the tree easily, in this case the list of items and its properties to the screen?

Check out the code:

**In Componenet**:

```
if (artists.items !== undefined) {
  return (
    <ul>
      { artists.items.map((artist, index) =>  <li key={index}>{`${artist}`}</li> )} 
    </ul>
  )
}
```

**In reducer Using inmmutableJS**:

```
  const initialState = Map({
  isFetching: false,
  artists: Map(),
  details: Map()
})


  export default function artist(state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_ARTISTS:
      return receiveArtists(state, action.artists)

    case FETCH_ARTISTS: 
      return fetchArtists(state)

    case RECEIVE_ARTIST_INFO:
      return receiveArtistInfo(state, action.artist)

    case FETCH_ARTIST_INFO:
     return fetchArtistInfo(state)

    default:
      return state 
    }
}
```

DATA

```
0:{external_urls: {…}, followers: {…}, genres: Array(3), href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5WUlDfRSoLAfcVSX1WnrxN", id: "5WUlDfRSoLAfcVSX1WnrxN", …}
1:{external_urls: {…}, followers: {…}, genres: Array(0), href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2nayTQuiuFt5fcSphlERqZ", id: "2nayTQuiuFt5fcSphlERqZ", …}
2:{external_urls: {…}, followers: {…}, genres: Array(0), href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2c8C6NJx7VyLathetev2Og", id: "2c8C6NJx7VyLathetev2Og", …}
```

Comment: What is artists, more specifically artists.items, passed to your component? Is it the artist Map from your reducer or are you trying to pass React components as props to another component? In the latter case, what is actually your intention with this approach?

Comment: artist comes from an API. The idea is to render the object to the screen. Im trying to pass it to another component

Comment: Well the thing is that apparently an artist is an object. If you are putting an object into a string like that ``${artist}`` it will give "[obj][Obj]". You have to target the object properties specifically like this: ``${artist.name}`` or whatever properties it has.

Comment: That works! I'm such a dumb**ss.. thank you!

Comment: how about ${artist.images} why does it return again ```[obj][obj]```?

Comment: Because it probably is an array. You can not simply render objects like this. If it is an array you have to map each element to render a component or if you want a string `${artist.images.join(', ')}`.

Comment: Will try that...  you got me rollin' again